# Quelle serait la modification permettant de rendre compte qu’il existe plus d’une paire de parenthèses (phrase/détails)?

Tags: choix-de-mot, constructions, formulation

Détails:

À titre de précision, l'auteur en question a entre autres transposé quelques termes d'une équation et il s'est débarrassé d'un facteur moins un en le distribuant sur les termes se trouvant entre parenthèses.

Le problème est qu’il y a plusieurs facteurs moins un se trouvant face à des parenthèses; dans le contexte, il n’est question que d’un seul facteur moins un et d’une seule paire de parenthèses. Je cherche une façon d’exprimer cette idée en prenant ce détail en considération.

Devrais-je écrire: « (...) se trouvant entre l’une des paires de parenthèses. » pour éviter l’ambiguïté? Ou bien selon le contexte le lecteur devrait être en mesure de comprendre sans cet ajout de termes.

Merci.

Comment: Je dois bien avouer que cette question me laisse perplexe. Serait-il possible de voir de quoi on parle exactement ?

Comment: On parle de mathématiques, de nombres, de variables et de parenthèses. Je ne peux être on ne peut plus clair à mon avis, enfin je pense en tout cas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ce n'est pas une méthode spécifique au français mais on peut utiliser la couleur du texte ou le surlignage pour mettre en évidence le facteur moins un et le bloc entre parenthèses concernés.

Comment: Salut jilliagre, tu as répondu implicitement à ma question... Ma question concernait la phrase que j’ai mentionnée dans les détails, nul besoin de se prendre la tête davantage... Je peux donc dire: «Il s’est débarrassé d’un facteur moins un en le distribuant sur les termes entre les parenthèses concernées. Voilà en quoi consistait ma question. Merci.

Comment: J'avais bien compris en quoi consistait ta question, la couleur est bien aussi...